# Using file_get_contents to different URLs in a loop seems to break the rest of the code

Tags: php, jquery, loops, xmlhttprequest, file-get-contents

I am currently trying to fetch some facebook data, which I then want to access in Javascript. Specifically, I am trying to access some characteristics of the user's friends.
So I am getting the user's friend list using file_get_contents to his graph API URL.
This provides me with an array of friend ids.

As I need a characteristic from each friend, I am doing:

```
foreach($dataarray as $friend) {
$friendurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$friend->id."?access_token=".$token."";
$fdata = json_decode(file_get_contents($friendurl));
if($fdata->gender == "male") {
 array_push($fulldata, $fdata->name);
    }
}
```

Having this code piece seems to break the javascript code, as none of my alert instructions are ran.

Also, inserting a break after the if, so that only one file_get_contents is done, seems to make the code runnable (but I obviously need to go through all of the friends).

How can I solve this?

I would use jQuery or xmlHttpRequest to do the HTTP GET, but somehow I always seem to get back a status code of 0, with an empty response.

Edit:
Here is the JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {

                alert('Test1');
                <?php

                $fulldata = array();

                $data = $result->data;

                foreach($data as $friend) {
                    $friendurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$friend->id."?access_token=".$token."";
                    //echo("alert(\"".$friendurl."\");");
                    $fdata = json_decode(file_get_contents($friendurl));
                    if($fdata->hometown->name) {
                        array_push($fulldata, $fdata->hometown->name);
                    }
                }
                echo ("alert(\"".count($fulldata)."\")");
                ?>

                }
         </script>
```

I should've also added that this is being done on a page embedded into facebook using the canvas feature.

Comment: There is no JS that shows alerts here.

Comment: I edited the question just in case you actually didn't understand what I meant.

Comment: The code you posted is pure PHP.. post the JS code that breaks and we'll be wiser.

Comment: Since you are outputting html with php, view the source in your browser to see what html (the <script></script> tag) it is generating and paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    return curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
}

foreach($dataarray as $friend){
    $friendurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$friend->id."?access_token=".$token."";
    $fdata = json_decode(curl($friendurl));
    if($fdata->gender == "male"){
            array_push($fulldata, $fdata->name);
        }
}
```

Maybe FGC is disabled but you don't get any notifications/warnings.

Code from comment:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: I got no luck with your solution, unfortunatly. But I think that my server does not have curl, and maybe that is why it is not working (I tested the code in the curl function that you posted, calling echo before and after init, and only the one before the init was successful). I get no error messages as well.

Comment: Add error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1); on top of your PHP, it must display messages if cURL is not installed. Also try changing HTTPS to HTTP, since there is no cURL maybe there is no SSL support also.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem is indeed that curl is not installed (call to undefined function curl_init()). About changing https to http, I can't do it, as facebook requires https for when you need to pass an access token.

Comment: Yup, haven't used FB for a while. Try using file_get_contents, I think problem is in SSL (HTTPS) support, maybe it will report error.

Answer (score -1):

Note that you are doing cross-domain AJAX call which is prohibited for security reasons.
You can do the api call on the server and echo the data to the client side JS, or you can build a php proxy return the result of the Graph API call(As the proxy is at your own server, they are in the same domain).